# Is there a standard way of expressing a pipe of processes as JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, pipe

If I have a process built out of several map functions, such as:

```
thing.map(get('value')).map(add(3)).map(toString)
```

Is there a standard or de-facto standard nomenclature for encoding the process (rather than the resulting data) in a string or as an array (or other form), that would be suitable for JSON? Something like:

```
"get:'value'|add:3|toString"
```

?

Comment: I don't know of any, but spontaneously I would have suggested something like `[{"name": "get", args: ["value"]}, {"name": "add", "args": [3]}, {"name": "toString", args: []}]`, if you want to be able to use this information to perform the process.

Comment: Yes, that's an option. It's quite verbose. But quicker than parsing a string.